# Binding Drop down with localized value using enum in C#

Tags: c#, .net, enums, dropdownbox

Binding Drop down with localized value using enum in C#.

I have value for all the languages. So I do not need to fetch it from anywhere else.
I can write all the value in different languages resx file. But I am not sure how it works.

I am using C# windows form. framework 3.5

Comment: What UI framework are you using here? WPF, asp.net, winforms, etc ...

Comment: Yeah. And what have you tried? It is not like there are not hooks for localization in most of the UI technologies in the .NET framework, sometimes with available editors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used following code and it works fine for me

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
```

.......

.......

.......

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(DDLLang.SelectedValue);
ComponentResourceManager resource = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Default));
resource.ApplyResources(LblName, "LblName");
LblName.ID = "LblName";
Response.Write(resource.GetString("strMsg",CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture)??resource.GetString("strMsg"));
```

In above code LblName is a Label and StrMsg a simple string.

In resource file I will write like this:

Name         Value

---

**Lbl.Name**   labelname................

**StrMsg**     anycustom msg............

Answer (score 1):

```
private static ResourceManager _resources = new ResourceManager("MyClass.myResources",
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

public static IEnumerable<string> GetLocalizedNames(this IEnumerable enumValues)
{
    foreach(var e in enumValues)
    {
        string localizedDescription = _resources.GetString(String.Format("{0}.{1}", e.GetType(), e));
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(localizedDescription))
        {
            yield return e.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            yield return localizedDescription;
        }
    }
}
```